# Having multiple IF functions in Excel: How to override one function over another

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2016

So I have a "status" cell that should tell me whether an item has been "listed", "sold", or "shipped".

It is possible for any particular item to be listed, sold, and shipped at the same time, but I want the priority of the status cell to go like this: (Shipped-Sold-Listed).

Each shipped, sold, and listed status pulls from other cells that may or may not include data.

So far I have this as my formula:

```
=IF(AND($K4)<>"","Shipped",IF(AND($F4)<>"","Sold",IF(AND($H4)<>"","Listed")))
```

Right now the "status" for one of my cells is "Shipped" but when I take away the data in the K4 cell (aka: shipped data) it says there is an error. If my function was right, the lack of data in K4 would have made the formula look for data in F4 and continue to the following IF function.

I don't know if I'm missing a tiny detail or if I'm doing this all wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remove that `AND()` function from your condition. It's not being used correctly and is totally not needed here anyway. `=IF($K4<>"","Shipped",IF($F4<>"","Sold",IF($H4<>"","Listed")))`

Comment: Wouldn't this do it? `If($K4="Shipped","Shipped",If($F4="Sold","Sold","Listed"))`

Comment: @DavidZemens I have a suspicion that the test on `H4` is necessary here and one possible result from this `If()` is `FALSE` or NULL depending on the needs of OP. If that's not true, then your solution is much cleaner :)

Comment: @JNevill Yeah that's a good consideration, either way, easy enough to fix :)

Comment: What's happening under the hood is that `And()` takes two conditions and tests them to see if they are BOTH true. You are only supplying one condition, and it's not even a condition, it's just the value of a cell. `AND(a1="hi", b1="there")` would be a proper use of `And()`. You however have `And(K4)`. This worked to return "Shipped" by accident. `True/False` values in Excel are equal to 1 (but actually any other number) as true and 0 as false. So... `And(500)` returns `FALSE` and `FALSE<>""` is `TRUE`. BUT... `And("")` is meaningless and throws an error as `""` can't be converted to a Boolean.

Comment: It just so happened that not only did your `K4` cell contain a value, but that value was a number (any number at all) that could be converted to a Boolean (True/False value) where `And()` was able to try to work instead of just giving up and barfing a `#VALUE`. Had `K4` been a string like `"Hi"` then `And("Hi")` would have barfed up the same error because `"Hi"` is neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE`.

Answer (score 4):

No need for `AND` - you just need to run down your logic in a nested `IF` formula:

`=IF($K4<>"","Shipped",IF($F4<>"","Sold",IF($H4<>"","Listed","")))`

Comment: you type faster than I do apparently

Comment: I was just finishing as I saw your comment come through :)